# Show that there exists $0 \neq v_0 \in H$ with $v_0 \perp V$ such that the supremum is attained.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, hilbert-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, compact-operators

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $V$ be an $m$-dimensional proper subspace of $H.$ Let $T \in \mathcal L (H)$ be a compact operator. Show that there exists $0 \neq v_0 \in H$ with $v_0 \perp V$ such that the supremum $$\sup\limits_{v \neq 0,\ v \perp V} \frac {\left \langle Tv, v \right \rangle} {\|v\|^2} = \frac {\left \langle Tv_0, v_0 \right \rangle} {\left \|v_0 \right \|^2}$$ i.e. the supremum is attained.

I tried by taking a maximizing sequence $\{u_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ in $H$ with $\|u_n\| = 1$ and $u_n \perp V$ for all $n \geq 1$ such that the sequence $\{\left \langle T u_n , u_n \right \rangle \}_{n \geq 1}$ converges to the supremum. Since $T$ is compact, the sequence $\{T u_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ will then have a convergent subsequence $\left \{T u_{n_k} \right \}_{k \geq 1}$ converging to some $y \in H.$ But how do I proceed from here? Could anyone give me some suggestion regarding this one?

Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT** $:$

Let $\alpha = \sup\limits_{v \neq 0,\ v \perp V} \frac {\langle Tv, v \rangle} {\|v\|^2}.$ Choose a sequence $\{u_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ of unit vectors in $V^{\perp}$ such that $\langle T u_n, u_n \rangle \to \alpha.$ Since $T$ is compact, so is $T^{\ast}$ and hence $\left \{T^{\ast} (u_n)\right \}_{n \geq 1}$ has a subsequence $\left \{T^{\ast} (u_{n_k}) \right \}_{k \geq 1}$ converging to some $\beta \in 
H.$ Now since $H$ is reflexive, $\left \{u_{n_k} \right \}_{k \geq 1}$ has a further subsequence which is weakly convergent. WLOG we may assume that $\left \{u_{n_k} \right \}_{k \geq 1}$ is weakly convergent converging to some $v_0 \in H.$ Then we have $$\begin{align*} \tag{1} \left \langle T u_{n_k}, u_{n_k} \right \rangle & = \left \langle T u_{n_k} - T v_0, u_{n_k} \right \rangle + \left \langle T v_0, u_{n_k} \right \rangle \end{align*}$$

Now, $$\begin{align*} \left \langle T u_{n_k} - T v_0, u_{n_k} \right \rangle & = \left \langle u_{n_k} - v_0, T^{\ast} u_{n_k} \right \rangle \\  & = \left \langle u_{n_k} - v_0, T^{\ast}  u_{n_k} - \beta  \right \rangle + \left \langle u_{n_k} - v_0, \beta \right \rangle \end{align*}$$

Clearly, both the terms on the RHS tend to zero and hence by $(1)$ we have $\left \langle T v_0, u_{n_k} \right \rangle \to \alpha$ as $\left \langle T u_{n_k}, u_{n_k} \right \rangle \to \alpha.$ But since the sequence $\left \{u_{n_k} \right \}_{k \geq 1}$ converges weakly to $v_0,$ it follows that $\left \langle T v_0, v_0 \right \rangle = \alpha.$

Also, $v_0 \in V^{\perp}$ because for any $w \in V$ we have $$\left \langle v_0, w \right \rangle = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \left \langle u_{n_k}, v \right \rangle = 0$$ since $u_{n_k} \in V^{\perp}$ for all $k \geq 1.$

But I can't determine why $\left \|v_0 \right \| = 1.$ Clearly $\|v_0\| \leq 1$ as $$\|v_0\| \leq \liminf\limits_{k \to \infty} \left \|u_{n_k} \right \| = 1.$$ So if $v_0 \neq 0,$ set $w_0 = \frac {v_0} {\left \|v_0 \right \|}.$ Then $\left \|w_0 \right \| = 1$ and $w_0 \perp V$ and so we have $$\alpha = \left \langle T v_0, v_0 \right \rangle = \|v_0\|^2 \left \langle T w_0, w_0 \right \rangle \leq \alpha \left \|v_0 \right \|^2.$$ So if $0 \lt \|v_0\| \lt 1$ we would have a contradiction.

So we are done if $v_0 \neq 0.$ If $v_0 = 0$ then $\alpha = 0.$ So for $\alpha \neq 0$ we are done.

How to tackle $\alpha = 0$ case?

Comment: May be this helps: $H$ is reflexive, so by the Eberlein-Smulian theorem $(u_{n_k})$ has a weakly convergent subsequence, and denote by $v_0$ its weak limit. This is (I think) the element you are looking for.

Comment: @Albert$:$ Devised a nice argument.

Comment: @Albert$:$ I have added an argument in the edit section. Could you please check it? I can't determine why $v_0$ will necessarily have norm $1.$

Comment: First, it is clear that $v_0\neq 0$. If $\|v_0\|<1$ then $\langle Tv_0,v_0\rangle/\|v_0\|^2 = \alpha/\|v_0\|^2>\alpha$ contradicting the fact that $\alpha=\sup_{v\neq 0} \langle Tv,v\rangle/\|v\|^2$. I think that's it, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Albert$:$ I have done exactly the same thing. But I have to ensure that $\|v_0\| = 1.$ Why $v_0 \neq 0\ $?

Comment: But what I said proves that $\|v_0\|\geq 1$ and you already know that $\|v_0\|\leq 1$.

Comment: @Albert$:$ Oh I see now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146343/discussion-between-albert-and-anacardium).

Comment: @Albert$:$ I missed one thing. If $\|v_0\| \lt 1$ then can you always divide by $\|v_0\|$ unless $v_0 \neq 0\ $? How do you show that $v_0 \neq 0\ $?